# Shopify Dawn Theme - Reduce Footer Size

Tags: css, shopify

I am creating my website and using the Dawn theme, from Shopify.

I want to reduce the footer size, since it looks too height:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tHGT.png)

I tried to use this code in section-footer.css, but didn't see any changes:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 750px) {
.footer-block__details-content {
    column-count: 3;
}
}
```

I've now added this code to the section-footer.css but nothing happened:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1BtJ.png]

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked for me:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 750px) {
    .footer {
        padding-top: 20px !important;
    }
    .footer__content-top {
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .footer__content-bottom {
        padding-top: 0;
    }
    .product--large:not(.product--no-media) .product__media-wrapper {
        max-width: 55%;
    }
    .product-media-container.constrain-height.media-fit-contain {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .product--large:not(.product--no-media) .product__info-wrapper {
        max-width: 45%;
    }
    .product__title h1 {
        font-size: 3.5rem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question may be better understood if it contain an explanation of why how it works. Perhaps try adding some inline comments to explain what each item does.

Answer (score 1):

modify the CSS for the `.footer` class

```
@media screen and (min-width: 750px) {
  .footer {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried pasting this code on the section-footer.css section but I don't see any changes, even if I change the padding-top or padding-bottom to 5px. I've edited the question and added a new screenshot.